# How would I parse JSON in Ruby to give me specific output

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, output, httparty

So I'm trying to make in Ruby so that it "Idk how to express myself" parse JSON from this API so the output is:

```
{"infected"=>19334, "deceased"=>429, "recovered"=>14047, "tested"=>515395, "tested24hours"=>8393, "infected24hours"=>351, "deceased24hours"=>11, "sourceUrl"=>"https://covid19.rs/homepage-english/", "lastUpdatedAtApify"=>"2020-07-15T14:00:00.000Z", "readMe"=>"https://apify.com/krakorj/covid-serbia"}
```

and I would like it to only show for example `"infected"=>19334,` as number `19334`

I'm new to Ruby programming I'm still learning it since it's COVID pandemic and lockdown I have more of free time and it kinda makes sense to make something related to it.

This is what I've done so far:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

url = 'https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value-stores/aHENGKUPUhKlX97aL/records/LATEST?disableRedirect=true'
response = HTTParty.get(url)
re = response.parsed_response
puts re
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you do it like this:

```
re["infected"]
 => 19334
```

HTTPParty parsed response returns a hash, so you access the value by the key. If the key is a "string", you access using a "string". If they key is a :symbol, you access with a :symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if that is your question, but `parsed_response` has already parsed the json and converted it into a hash.

So to access the `infected` field, you can just do

```
 re = response.parsed_response
 infected = re["infected"]
 puts infected
```

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I prefer using 'open-uri'.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

url = 'https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value-stores/aHENGKUPUhKlX97aL/records/LATEST?disableRedirect=true'
response = open(url)
json = JSON.parse(response)

puts json["infected"]
```

-> output 19334

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

url = 'https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value- 
stores/aHENGKUPUhKlX97aL/records/LATEST?disableRedirect=true'
response = HTTParty.get(url)
re = response.parsed_response
```

At this stage we have that output

```
{"infected"=>19334, "deceased"=>429, "recovered"=>14047, "tested"=>515395, "tested24hours"=>8393, "infected24hours"=>351, "deceased24hours"=>11, "sourceUrl"=>"https://covid19.rs/homepage-english/", "lastUpdatedAtApify"=>"2020-07-15T14:10:00.000Z", "readMe"=>"https://apify.com/krakorj/covid-serbia"}
```

You can access any above variable value like that

```
infected = re["infected"]
deceased = re["deceased"]
```

And so on..